# Inject all dependencies automatically in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm currently trying to implement Spring Dependency Injection into my Desktop Application (I am only trying to inject my services).

Apparently I dont really understand how it works, despite all the tutorials (most of them address web applications though). So the current state is that I have added a dependency in my pom.xml to add the spring jars, which works properly. I also managed to scan for my services. application-Context.xml:

```xml
<beans
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="FireworksApp" />

</beans>
```

I am pretty sure that I have to tell Spring where my application-Context.xml is. Therefore I have found a loader class in a guide:

```
public class ApplicationContextLoader {

protected ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

public ConfigurableApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}

/**
 * Loads application context. Override this method to change how the
 * application context is loaded.
 * 
 * @param configLocations
 *            configuration file locations
 */
protected void loadApplicationContext(String... configLocations) {
    applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            configLocations);
    applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
}

/**
 * Injects dependencies into the object. Override this method if you need
 * full control over how dependencies are injected.
 * 
 * @param main
 *            object to inject dependencies into
 */
protected void injectDependencies(Object main) {
    getApplicationContext().getBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(
            main, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO, false);
}

/**
 * Loads application context, then injects dependencies into the object.
 * 
 * @param main
 *            object to inject dependencies into
 * @param configLocations
 *            configuration file locations
 */
public void load(Object main, String... configLocations) {
    loadApplicationContext(configLocations);
    injectDependencies(main);
}
}
```

Unfortunately this loader only loads dependencies for a given object. But I don't want to have to manually load dependencies for every Panel I have. So the final question is: How can I tell Spring where my applicationContext is and to inject all dependencies automatically without having to load it manually for every object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to go through the `ApplicationContextLoader` hurdle that you have setup. Spring provides easy means of bootstrapping any application, including a desktop one.

Just do the following:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext; 

public class SpringApplicationContextExample
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    new Main();
  }

  public SpringApplicationContextExample()
  {
    // open/read the application context file
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-Context.xml");

    // retrieve a bean for class SomeSpringService
    SomeSpringService someSpringService = (SomeSpringService)ctx.getBean("someSpringService");

    //do whatever with the bean
  }

}
```

The code above is taken from [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/load-spring-application-context-file-java-swing-application) blog post and works if `application-Context.xml` is at the root of the classpath (for example right under the `resources` directory of maven project).

Using the code above, Spring will automatically create and wire all the beans that have been specified

Note that the code above is sort of the old-school Spring way of doing things. [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) provided a much more pleasant way of getting started. [Here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) is an example and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple) is another

Comment: tbh I dont like the old school spring way. The accessing data-jpa doesnt really seem to do what i was asking. After about 4 hours I still havent gotten the githubg example to run... Idk, Im propably doing something wrong, but Im doing like exactly the same as in all the examples.

Comment: Have you checked out the code from github or are you copying it? If you are doing the later, you might have missed something

Comment: Well, I got the example working. Still not working in my project. My Main class has Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration, ComponentScan Annotations and my Service class has Component. And my pom.xml is identical with the example pom.xml aside from the name...

Comment: haha :X i have overseen to run it with springapplication.run(). It still doesnt work properly though. If my main class is not in the package of the class that i want autowired it says: No qualifying bean of type [FireworksApp.Service.ProjectService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. If its in the package of the service the service just gets autowired with null.

Comment: I guess I pretty much got it